# Replacing submit button with value

Tags: javascript

I inherited a web page that had some HTML that looked like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="1">Submit 1</input>
<input type="submit" value="2">Submit 2</input>
<input type="submit" value="3">Submit 3</input>
```

I need to change this code so that I can do use the following instead

```
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmitClick(1);">Submit 1</input>
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmitClick(2);">Submit 2</input>
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmitClick(3);">Submit 3</input>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSubmitClick(val) {
    // do something with val
    $('#myForm').submit();
  }
</script>
```

My question is, with the first code, the server received the "value" (i.e. 1, 2, 3). In the code I'm changing to, 1, 2, and 3 are no longer binding to my server code. How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a value to your form, and then you can set the value, and send it to your PHP server:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmitClick(1);">Submit 1</input>
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmitClick(2);">Submit 2</input>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submitid">


<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSubmitClick(val) {
    // do something with val
    $('#submitid').val(val)
    $('#myForm').submit();
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSubmitClick(val) {
    // do something with val
    $('#myForm').submit();
  }
</script>
```

In this example, I created a value by using new `<input>` HTML tag. I set it to `hidden` so the user not see it and will not change it (it only can be changed from JavaScript and dev tools)

I gave it the ID of the tag, and using jQuery `val` function to set the value from the function argument.

**More info:**

- [jQuery val function](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [Forms: Hidden Field](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally: Use a regular submit button and progressively enhance with JavaScript.

This might not be possibly if you need to do something asynchronous in the JavaScript, in which case: **Store the value in a hidden input in the form.**

Ideally, keep using a regular submit button when you do this.

For example, since you are using jQuery already:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <button value="1">Submit 1</button>
    <button value="2">Submit 2</button>
    <button value="3">Submit 3</button>
</form>

<script>
    $f = $("#myForm");
    $f.find("button[type=submit]").on("click", remember_button);
    $f.on("submit", on_submit_click);

    function remember_button() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var $remembered_button = $f.find(".remembered_button");
        if (!$remembered_button.length) {
            $remembered_button = $("<input>")
                .attr("type", "hidden")
                .attr("name", "button_value")
                .addClass("remembered_button")
                .appendTo($f);
        }
        $remembered_button.val(val);
    }

    on_submit_click(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var val = $f.find(".remembered_button").val();
        $f.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said, seeing you are using jQuery already there is another alternative.

You could write a custom event, use `val` and then merge it with the form data before manually posting it using a [**$.ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://YourTargetUrl" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input name="ExampleFormData" type="text">

  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="1">Submit 1
  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="2">Submit 2
  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="3">Submit 3
</form>
```

I added `data-type="submit"` above purely to have a selector to target for bindings, you can do it which ever way, classes, input type, etc.. I leave that up to you.

The additional Input is only to show that all form data you might have is posted as usual.

Using the below JavaScript, you can bind a custom `click` event to the buttons, extract the value of the clicked button, use the value for what ever process you need to use it for and then post your request manually, including `val` along with the form data.

```
$('[data-type=submit]').on('click', function(e, val) {
  var $form = $('#myForm');
  var val = this.value;
  // do somethign with val

  var data = $form.serializeArray();

  // add val to the post data, using the variable name on the server as "name" for the serialize on the server side to map it to the correct variable.
  data.push({
    name: "theNameOfYourVariableOnServerReceivingVal",
    value: val
  });

  // Manually execute a post request to the server
  // Using the form's action attribute, containing the target URL to post to
  // and using $.param to serialize the data array before posting
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $form[0].action,
    data: $.param(data)
  });
});
```

If you must reload the page as your previous submit did you can make use of the `$.ajax` `success` or `complete` callback function like this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $form[0].action,
  data: $.param(data),
  success: function() {
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

The benefit of using an ajax call is that at the same time you can make use of the `error` callback, processing any errors from the server and for example show them on the UI if needed while at the same time only reloading the page on a `success` request.

Another benefit is that you can add more data as needed from anywhere to the request, logical data as well as values from elements outside the form tags.

---

The snippet below has `location.reload()` commented out so you can see the console entries of the form data.

```js
$('[data-type=submit]').on('click', function(e, val) {
  var $form = $('#myForm');
  var val = this.value;
  // do somethign with val

  var data = $form.serializeArray();

  // add val to the post data, using the variable name on the server as "name" for the serialize on the server side to map it to the correct variable.
  data.push({
    name: "theNameOfYourVariableOnServerReceivingVal",
    value: val
  });
  
  //shows the merged form data to post
  console.log(data);
  
  //shows the form data serialized for the request
  console.log($.param(data));

  // Manually execute a post request to the server
  // Using the form's action attribute, containing the target URL to post to
  // and using $.param to serialize the data array before posting
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $form[0].action,
    data: $.param(data),
    success: function() {
      // Only executes when the request was successful

      // If you want to reload the page only when a request was successful
      // reload it manually on success
      //location.reload();
    },
    error: function() {
      // Only executes when the request returns with an error

      // If you want to deal with error from the server
      // do it in here
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Executes all the time when a request completed, regardless of error or success.

      // If you must reload the page everytime, ignoring error
      // reload the page manually on complete.
      //location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input name="ExampleFormData" type="text">

  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="1">Submit 1
  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="2">Submit 2
  <input data-type="submit" type="button" value="3">Submit 3
</form>
```